# Can't connect to MariaDB via PhpStorm but terminal works fine

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, phpstorm

[image]

I can't figure out why PhpStorm won't connect to my database. I'm using the same credentials as I do the command-line.

MariaDB is running under Docker, not sure if that makes a difference.

What might be the problem?

I'm using the `mariadb:10.4` docker image w/ minimal config changes:

```
[mysqld]
default_time_zone = '+00:00'
sql_mode            = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION,PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

---

MariaDB is configured like this in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    mariadb:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/mariadb.docker
        restart: "no" # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - ./docker/20200119_162812.sql.gz:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql.gz:ro
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
```

```
MariaDB [busman]> \s
--------------
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Connection id:          10
Current database:       busman
Current user:           root@172.18.0.1
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution        Protocol version:       10
Connection:             127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 2 min 17 sec
```

---

I tried adding some logging:

```
command: [mysqld,--general-log=1,--general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/general-log.log]
```

When I connect via terminal it spits a bunch of stuff out:

```
200203  0:56:21     10 Connect  root@172.18.0.1 as anonymous on busman
                    10 Query    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1,SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1000,MAX_JOIN_SIZE=1000000                        10 Query    show databases
                    10 Query    show tables
                    10 Field List       billing_items
                    10 Field List       booking_groups
                    10 Field List       booking_segments
                    10 Field List       booking_stops
                    10 Field List       bookings
                    10 Field List       companies
                    10 Field List       company_aliases
                    10 Field List       company_surveys
                    10 Field List       countries
                    10 Field List       country_timezone
                    10 Field List       customers
                    10 Field List       driver_jobs
                    10 Field List       email_cc
                    10 Field List       failed_jobs
                    10 Field List       features
                    10 Field List       fee_stacks
                    10 Field List       fees
                    10 Field List       google_calendar_errors
                    10 Field List       google_calendars
                    10 Field List       guids
                    10 Field List       invoice_item_stacks
                    10 Field List       invoice_items
                    10 Field List       jobs
                    10 Field List       menu_options
                    10 Field List       menu_options_enabled
                    10 Field List       migrations
                    10 Field List       package_fees
                    10 Field List       package_vehicles
                    10 Field List       packages
                    10 Field List       password_new_user
                    10 Field List       password_reminders
                    10 Field List       password_resets
                    10 Field List       payments
                    10 Field List       permission_groups
                    10 Field List       permissions
                    10 Field List       role_permissions
                    10 Field List       roles
                    10 Field List       stripe_keys
                    10 Field List       subscription_plans
                    10 Field List       timezones
                    10 Field List       user_activity_log
                    10 Field List       user_blocked_dates
                    10 Field List       user_roles
                    10 Field List       users
                    10 Field List       vehicle_blocked_dates
                    10 Field List       vehicle_distance_rates
                    10 Field List       vehicle_features
                    10 Field List       vehicles
                    10 Query    select @@version_comment limit 1
200203  0:56:23     10 Quit
```

But not a peep when I try connecting with PhpStorm.

Comment: Its a connection refused, so its a network problem more than a mariadb configuration problem. How is your docker instance started? Are you exporting ports? Are you sure you command-line is using the same instance rather an a mariadb on the host. Use `\s` in the command-line to verify its using a TCP connection rather than a socket.

Comment: @danblack I'm starting the docker instance w/ `docker-compose up`. Yes, I'm exporting the port (see update). I don't have any databases or anything running on 3306 on my host machine. Yes, it's running on TCP. There is one thing I just thought of though -- I'm running Docker under WSL2 and PhpStorm is running under Windows 10. I wonder if WSL doesn't share it's faux-networks with Windows? HTTP does work in browsers running under Windows though, so it's strange that 3306 wouldn't work. And if it's "refused" that means that it's being seen but rejected, right?

Comment: What about Windows Firewall (or another one, e.g. Internet Security suite etc)? Can you connect from an ordinary terminal (cmd.exe) launched within IDE?

Comment: I tried w/ the the Windows firewall off, no luck. I don't have a Windows command-line sql client to test. Bash/WSL inside IDE terminal works. `netstat -a -n -b` in an elevated cmd.exe shows the expected ports as listening.

Comment: OK, I downloaded a windows command-line client and indeed I cannot connect through that. How come HTTP works?

Comment: I should have looked more closely at what netstat was saying, I'm kind of a networking noob. Says `TCP    [::1]:5432             [::]:0                 LISTENING`. I assume that means it's listening on ipv6. And indeed, `psql.exe -h[::1]` works, `psql.exe -hlocalhost` works, but `psql.exe -h127.0.0.1` does not. I guess JDBC doesn't support IPv6? https://mpen.xyz/share/2020/02/phpstorm64_2020-02-04_00-19-09.png I wonder if I can get docker to use IPv4...

Comment: Changing docker-compose.yml to forward to my host IP (e.g. `172.29.148.172:5432:5432`) and then connecting explicitly through that IP works https://mpen.xyz/share/2020/02/phpstorm64_2020-02-04_00-34-27.png but it's not ideal because that IP isn't fixed.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you put in docker-compose, I just have to use my IP when connecting with PhpStorm's driver. Same for the Docker TCP IP https://mpen.xyz/share/2020/02/phpstorm64_2020-02-04_00-57-27.png not sure if this is WSL causing it to not bind on both IPv6 and IPv4 or a Windows 10 thing or a Docker thing...